# Constant in enum not seen in define

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

I have such a code in **C**

```
enum {
     MYVAR = 1
};

#ifdef MYVAR
#define VAR 1
#else
#define VAR 2
#endif

printf("VAR = %d", VAR);
```

in this case it will prints "VAR = 2".

Is there any way to get preprocessor see the definition in `enum`?

Comment: You are talking about two different things here, the *preprocessor* and the *compiler*.  The preprocessor runs before the compiler, and has no notion of things like enums.

Comment: You right. But in the normal case the preprocessor can see the names of the variables I use.

Comment: Is `MYVAR 1` even valid C?

Comment: The preprocessor has no idea about anything to do with C.  So variables, enums, types, etc. are essentially invisible.  It's all just text as far as the preprocessor is concerned.

Comment: Sure there was a misstype in the code. Thanks  ta.speot.is

Comment: Where is my favourite 'poster should demonstrate some understanding' closing reason?

Comment: "it in the normal case the preprocessor can see the names of the variables I use" -- No it can't, it only sees their text. The preprocessor operates on tokens but has no understanding of C language semantics beyond the preprocessor pass.

Comment: @qrdl They took it away for some reason. We'll have to either close a lot fewer bad questions, or use inaccurate reasons to close them.

Comment: @JimBalter Or type them in manually...

Comment: @glglgl Ah, true, the "Other" category provides a lot of latitude.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't show a minimum understanding of the subject.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't show a minimum understanding of the subject

Comment: qrdl - everyone starts somewhere :) Look at it as an opportunity to mentor a budding developer rather than disappointment because he's not a CompSci major.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. `#ifdef` and `#if` are part of preprocessor, which completes its run before the portion of the compiler that "understands" `enum`s.

`#ifdef` works only with preprocessor constants (i.e. things defined with `#define`, or passed to the compiler on the command line, say, with a `-DMYVAR=123` option).

`#if` works with integer and character constants, and preprocessor constants. All identifiers which are not preprocessor constants are considered undefined, and interpreted as if they were zeros when evaluating `#if` conditions. This includes `enum` constants.

Comment: " replaced with zero" -- no (or misleading). They are evaluated as 0 within #if expressions ... they aren't treated as 0 in other contexts, and are never textually replaced with 0

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks for the correction! That was indeed misleading.